# Java help needed for printing user entered string variable

Tags: java, input, printing, syntax

I'm trying to write a program that accepts user input for their full name and their gender (m/f).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CSCD210Lab2 { // class declaration

public static void main(String[]args) { // main method
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for console input
    System.out.print("Enter Your Full Name: ");
    String fullName;
    fullName = userInput.next( );

    System.out.print = fullName; // print user input
    }
}
```

At the moment, I only have the code for the user entering their name. I wanted to make sure the fullName variable was being stored, so I tried to have the console print whatever the user typed. However, I'm getting a syntax error on the `System.out.print = fullName;`. It gives me this error message:

```
CSCD210Lab2.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.print = fullName;
                ^
  symbol:   variable print
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
  1 error
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Bad syntax. System.out.print is a function, and as such is not eligible to be a left-hand-side of an assignment operation. Try this

```
System.out.print(fullName); 
//or
System.out.println(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a method, not a variable:

```
System.out.print(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.next()` go ahead and try putting this in instead: `userInput.nextLine();`

Meaning just add the `.nextLine()` method call instead of the `next()` method. 
Also `System.out.println("text goes here ");`
Is how this function is used.
Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
fullName = userInput.nextLine();    //next()will stop with first space ,so it is not compatible with your code , but it is right
System.out.print(fullName);//print() is method you need to pass  to it argument not to assign to it values like variables
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and tested and found that when you use,

`System.out.print`

you need to include the parenthesis () after print. Regardless if it's just a variable being printed like `fullName`

So here would be your fix

```
System.out.print(fullName);
```

Also, I notice that when you enter the full name, it only prints the first name. In order to fix this, use the method `nextLine();` instead of `next();`

This will allow the full name to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CSCD210Lab2 { // class declaration

public static void main(String[]args) { 
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Enter Your Full Name: ");
String fullName;
fullName = userInput.nextLine( );

System.out.print(fullName); // print user input
}
}
```

Complete code is here.
`nextline()` will allow you to take spaces between entrties. Each line will be considered as single entry.

Cheers!!